# PHP variable length of POST request?

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to submit an html form to a php server. However, this form can have a variable length and structure (I add input nodes through dynamic javascript as the user interacts with the page, depending on his actions). How can I pick up the values contained in the form from PHP (using $_POST['xxx']) if I don't know the structure of the form?

Comment: First of all, if you do not know the structure of recieving data and accept any data, you could have some serious security issues in future.  It is will be better to pass some dynamic fields as an array (so could be detached from static values) as well as to limit them for some types (so could be validated).

Comment: any advised reading on the topic?

Comment: @Xenos put my idea in comments below. Also read about `filter_input` on manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To loop through each of the POST values, use:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo "POST parameter $key has $value";
}
```

Comment: Using ``<input ... name="object[tree][N]"/>`` instead of plain ``name="object-tree-0"`` in the HTML/javascript should make the ``$_POST`` structure clearer as PHP will preserve the array-like ``$_POST['tree'][N]``.

Comment: bam, just like that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a fun (but valid) answer, existing answer on this question is good enough.

> if I don't know the structure of the form?

Then you can simply review

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and you'll get to know the structure of what was `POST`ed

Answer (score 0):

To find the structure of the POST OR GET OR SESSION values, you can print  using

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); print_r($_REQUEST); print_r($_SESSION);
```

---

You can find easily what exactly printing/structure of POST/REQUEST/SESSION.. etc

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Easy and clean.